# SET Date in COLA (It can't contain duplicate value) of type TIMESTAMP in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

If the COLA is not allowed to hold duplicate value. Could you please suggest approach to update only DATE part of timestamp from "2017-03-29" to "2017-03-31" in a single query, instead of running query for each row.

Example:
Current Table Values:

```
COLA 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.100000 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.200000 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.300000 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.400000 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.500000
```

Expected Table Value:

```
COLA 
2017-03-31-00.00.00.100000 
2017-03-31-00.00.00.200000 
2017-03-31-00.00.00.300000 
2017-03-31-00.00.00.400000 
2017-03-31-00.00.00.500000
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Column data type? Add 2 days, or 48 hours.

Comment: Column is of type TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add two days to each value:

```
update mytable set cola=cola+2 days
```